# Nesting XmlReader

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have a need to search through an xml file, find a data set, examine a second xml file, check if there is related data, and then move on to the next data set.

Here's some sample code to illustrate:

```
XmlReader XmlDoc1 = XmlReader.Create("~/data/xml/myxml1.xml",settings);
XmlReader XmlDoc2= XmlReader.Create("~/data/xml/myxml2.xml",settings);

using (XmlDoc1) {
    XmlDoc1.Open();
    //get a data node
    using(XmlDoc2){
        XmlDoc2.Open();
        //find related information... if it's there
        XmlDoc2.Close();
   }
   //do stuff
   XmlDoc1.Close();
}
```

I'm pretty sure the above code would produce an error, but it would be too time consuming to read XmlDoc1, get a data set, close it, search XmlDoc2, close it... wash, rinse, repeat. So, I'm looking for a speedy way to accomplish the above.

Before you ask, I cannot run a DB on this site, so XML will have to suffice.

Comment: I personally would use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` classes to parse your xml

Comment: that was my first build... too slow. The xml files in question fairly sizable.

Comment: though... I have not looked at XDocument...hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem opening two readers at the same time. However you cannot reuse `XmlDoc2` after disposing it (through the `using` block).

`XmlReader` is forward-only, so basically you'd be running through `XmlDoc2` for each iteration.

If speed is your concern, you could try let `XmlDoc1` be an `XmlReader` (as you're running through it from top to bottom, once) and use one of the suggested `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` classes for the inner xml.

Comment: While noodling this through, I was starting to think the same thing... so that's something I didn't know, you can only open and close a Reader (SQL or otherwise) once? That's probably been the source of the error that I've seen before. I'll give this a try.

Comment: For `IDataReader`s (SQL readers) you can usually only have one open per connection at the same time. An `XmlReader` should not care about other `XmlReader`s (unless they share the same data source, but in your case there are two different files).